# Organize imports in VS Code removes my preact import

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, preact

For the JavaScript:

```js
import { render, h } from "preact";

render(<p>Hello World!</p>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

When I run VS Code's `Organize Imports` command, the import for `h` is incorrectly removed:

```js
import { render } from "preact";

render(<p>Hello World!</p>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Organize imports removes unreferenced imports. In this case, VS Code does not understand that `h` is implicitly referenced by the jsx elements. You need to tell VS Code that you are using `h` as the react factory function

To fix this, create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) at the root of your project with the contents:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "h",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

You can find more information about these settings [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). `jsxFactory` can be set to whatever namespace your library uses to construct jsx elements, for example: `"h"` or `"React.createElement"`